# Script function not found: doGet (AGAIN !!! )

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, get

So I've read just about every article and thread I could about getting this to work and it seems to be a common issue with a varying range of causes. I couldn't find the solution so I'm hoping you guys can help.

I published the script and got the typical (Script function not found: doGet).

Here's the script and html script code. I've uploaded the new published link to the html file. I was sure to make a "New" version instead of updating the old version. I'm assuming there's some syntax somewhere that I haven't called out properly. I just don't know what or where. Hoping you can help.

Here's the script code:

```
    var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
    var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

    function intialSetup () {
      var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
    }

    function doPost (e) {
      var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
      lock.tryLock(10000)

      try {
        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
        var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

        var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
        var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

        var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
          return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
        })

        sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

        return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
      }

      catch (e) {
        return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
      }

      finally {
        lock.releaseLock()
      }
    }
```

Here's the script inside the HTML code

```
    <script>
        const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwzy6qtuvcOpOrl9ELoy6lM9k5CFhZWGbb-XriD1SyofDeZ6tU/exec'
        const form = document.forms['google-sheet']
      
        form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
            .then(response => alert("Thanks for Contacting us..! We Will Contact You Soon..."))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
        })
      </script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well there isn't a `doGet` function in your code. Is there?

Answer (score 1):

`doGet` is required when the web app URL is opened by using a web browser. The code included in the question doesn't include this function.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web