# Script function not found :doGet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I am trying to build a web app using google script and html form.The webapp works perfectly when I have the html file locally. But when I embed my html into a google site, this does not work. It reports "Script function not found: doGet"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script function not found: doGet (AGAIN !!! )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209291/script-function-not-found-doget-again)

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web):

> Both standalone scripts and scripts bound to Google Workspace
> applications can be turned into web apps, so long as they meet the
> requirements below.
>
> Requirements for web apps
>
> A script can be published as a web app if it meets these requirements:
>
> - It contains a **doGet(e)** or doPost(e) function.
> - The function returns an
>   HTML service HtmlOutput object or a Content service TextOutput object.

Take a look at [Serve HTML as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#serve_html_as_a_web_app) for the bare minimum you need in place.